# Cocos2d 2.x ARC issue on device

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, linker-errors, mach-o

I'm working on a game that has cocos2d with ARC.
The game builds & runs fine in Simulator, but when I build for device I get `Apple Mac-O Linker Errors`, saying that I'm missing the libraries for libcocos2d.a etc.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/aleksandartrpeski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jellyfish-fsomqwhqasishxcfzhgvccrdvzpt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/aleksandartrpeski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jellyfish-fsomqwhqasishxcfzhgvccrdvzpt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocosDenshion.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/aleksandartrpeski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jellyfish-fsomqwhqasishxcfzhgvccrdvzpt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libkazmath.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/aleksandartrpeski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jellyfish-fsomqwhqasishxcfzhgvccrdvzpt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/liblibpng.a'
```

When I go to the folder where the file is missing I only see jellyfish.app.

I don't have much experience in this kind of issues & I'm not clear why this happens,
I checked how to start the project from TinyTimGames & LearnCocos2D, still not clear what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved the issue, the builds for the binaries were somehow ignored by XCode because they were for another architecture, by settings the build settings for the cocos2d target `Build For Active Architectures Only` to `NO`, the issue dissapeared.

Comment: issue still remains for me

Comment: @DainiusKreivys I wouldn't know if this is still relevant, since 5 years past from it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'll have to add these libraries to the Link Binary With Libraries build phase.

See my [tutorial on Enabling ARC for Cocos2D projects](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/) for details.

It's strange that it would work for the Simulator though, since it's using the same target. I wouldn't rule out that the device is incompatible, you'll have to have at least a 3rd generation (iPhone 3GS) device running iOS 4.0 or higher.

Comment: I have them there, without that it won't build for Simulator too..
From the error logs I don't know why it searches for .a files in that directory when there's only an .app file.

Comment: Also the .a files from cocos2d are red in Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase, which I guess means that they're not present & should be built when the project will be built, so why is it asking for them in the Derived Data directory?

Comment: Ignore the red part, it has no real meaning (the highlight is broken in Xcode since like forever). Of course it searches in that folder and can't find them there because the problem is the .a files haven't been created (or stored elsewhere). Check Xcode - Preferences - Locations and make sure Derived Data + Advanced are set to Default and Unique respectively.

Comment: I solved the issue, the answer is below, for future reference.

Comment: Anyway I appreciate your work & commitment you have for the cocos2d community :)